# Loading environment modules within a python script

Tags: python, module, environment-variables, environment-modules

Is there a way for a python script to load and use [environment modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/)? `os.system('module load xxx')` doesn't work since it executes them in a subshell (at least, I think that's what's happening).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I know this question's kind of old but it's still relevant enough that I was looking for the answer, so I'm posting what I found that works as well:

At least in the 3.2.9+ sources, you can include the python "init" file to get a python function version of module:

```
>>> exec(open('/usr/local/Modules/default/init/python.py').read())
>>> module('list')
No Modulefiles Currently Loaded.
>>> module('load','foo')
>>> module('list')
Currently Loaded Modulefiles:
  1) foo/1.0
```

I've been told earlier versions can do the same without the .py extension, but that's second hand, so ymmv.

Alternative "init" file location (from comment by @lib): `/usr/share/Modules/init/python.py`

To use with Python 3, version 4.0 or later of Environment Modules is required, as that is the first version to have a bug-free Python3-compliant version of the Python init file.

Comment: This is much closer to what we actually use (since the `popen` calls to `modulecmd` are in the `python.py` file that you cited), so I'll set this to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I had nearly a heart attack figuring this out! Thank you very much.

Comment: In the server I am using it is in /usr/share/Modules/init/python.py . I found the path be running module --version (the correct entry seems MODULES_INIT_DIR)

Comment: Cool,  I found this answer looking for a solution for perl, and my particular setup (VERSION 3.2.7 on RHEL 6.2) has initialization code for several shells in /usr/share/Modules/init/: bash, csh, ksh, perl, python, sh, tcsh, and zsh.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: execfile() is deprecated in python 3.6.0. How to use exec statement with python 3.6 to use environment modules?

Comment: Thanks @Jarvis. The answer has been updated for Python 3

Answer (score 4):

One of our admins was able to solve the problem for me using `os.popen()` calls to `modulecmd`:

```
cmd = os.popen('/path/to/modulecmd python load my-module')
exec(cmd)
```

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted solution works, I found it to be easier to write:

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/environment/modules')
# Environment modules become available by loading python.py (the name choice could be better here)
from python import module

# ...
module('use', '/some/dir')
module('load', 'program/1.2.3')
```

This looks more pythonic to me and also it allows IDEs to offer auto-completion etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but here's one possible workaround, depending on your environment.  Assuming you can preface your system command with `ENVVAR=value`, you can do something along these lines:

```
import os
os.environ['EDITOR'] = 'vi'
cmd = "EDITOR=%(EDITOR)s $EDITOR" % os.environ
os.system(cmd)
```

The code assigns **vi** to your EDITOR environment variable, then passes it on the command line and runs the command, which (in this case) is EDITOR.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answers from jnewman, andreee and ian quite helpful. However, in my case the `$MODULESHOME/init/python.py` is written in Python 2 and is incompatible with Python 3 (it uses `exec output` instead of `exec(output)`). Here is my modified version that supports Python 3:

```py
import os
import subprocess

def load_module(module_name, *, capture_output=True, check=True, **kw):
    module_home = os.environ["MODULESHOME"]
    modulecmd = os.path.join(module_home, "bin/modulecmd")
    process = subprocess.run(
        [modulecmd, "python", "load", module_name],
        capture_output=capture_output,
        check=check,
        **kw,
    )
    return process
```

Example use case:

```py
CONDA_MODULE = "Anaconda3/2022.05"
load_module(CONDA_MODULE)
print(subprocess.check_output(["conda", "--help"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).decode("utf8"))
```