# How can i load Module packages of linux using a python script

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to python and am learning things by writing scripts.
I have tried the following and none of them seem to be working.

1) `commands.getoutput('module load xxx')`

2) `subprocess.check_output(['module load', xxx'])`

None of these change the environment as a side effect of the `module` call. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: By loading a module, do you mean `modprobe`?

Comment: I meant loading/switching of Environment modules .                                 ex: module load gcc/3.1.1, module switch gcc gcc/3.2.0 etc

Comment: I am not familiar with this `module`. I found a reference for it on modules.sourceforge.net, but seems innaccessible. Can you give some reference for further help?

Comment: From what I read, I assume `module` just does changes to the shell's environment, so unless you start a subshell you won't have any of its effects. None of the variants you are using fit this need.

Comment: Yes module just changes the shell environment alone. As far as i see, when we change the shell environment, the current shell for which you have modified will have the new environment modules set. Can you tell me which method will work. I think this link will give you more details http://hpc.ucla.edu/hoffman2/computing/modules.php

Comment: The thing is that your methods don't create a shell, but call the process directly. You could even try something like `getoutput("bash -c module ...")` but this would only affect the shell created inside that call, not the shell form which you call the python script. I tend to believe that the effect you want can't be achieved from inside a python script.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anyone, I managed to do it by prefixing all commands that depend on the module with `module load xxx &&`. For example,

```
module load mpi/mpich && mpirun ./myprogram -n 4 -options
```

Not an elegant solution, but works for me. There's also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427040/loading-environment-modules-within-a-python-script) answer but I couldn't make it work in the system I have access to.

Answer (score 0):

I found a different approach to solve this problem.
I have written a shell script which load s the environment modules and i am calling that in the python script.

Something like this

import subprocess
subprocess.call(['./module_load.sh'])

and the script has something like this....

module load ***

This seems to be working.

Have to say.....its pretty simple in Perl. it provides the environment modules package to handle this.

Comment: Out of curiosity: are you sure that after `subprocess.call` the environment available to the python process knows of the changes? Do you mind posting the effect of `os.getenv(...)` before and after this call, for some variable you know to be changed by `module`?

Comment: This does not load the modules outside the scope of the bash script.

Answer (score 0):

Both commands create a subshell  where the module is loaded - the problem is that this subshell is destroyed the moment Python function terminates