# How to source a bash file having module loads?

Tags: python, bash, python-2.x

This is the python code:

```python
#!/tool/pandora64/bin/python2.7.5

import os

shellFileName = "envVaribles.sh"
startUpFilePath = 'source /proj/pdkfc8/users/srikumar/phython/testEnv/' + shellFileName
print(startUpFilePath)
os.system(startUpFilePath)
```

This is the bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

module load cadenceICOA
module load calibre
```

When I tried to load the bash script from the terminal (source bash file) it is working fine.
When I tried to load using python code it is saying `module: command not found`.

Comment: What is `module` command? Have you added the directory that has it to your $PATH?

Comment: when i run the bash script in terminal it doesn't complaint...based on that i am thinking directory is added to the $PATH

Comment: `module: command not found` clearly shows that it's *not* added to $PATH.

Comment: Do the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427040/loading-environment-modules-within-a-python-script) solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can execute the bash script:

```
...
path = '/proj/pdkfc8/users/srikumar/phython/testEnv/' + shellFileName
startUpFilePath = path
...
```

or you can invoke the bash with the script

```
path = '/proj/pdkfc8/users/srikumar/phython/testEnv/' + shellFileName
startUpFilePath = '/bin/bash ' + path
...
```

Comment: After using above solution.....still i am seeing "module: command not found"

Comment: check in the terminal `which module` - it should give you full path to `module`, then update `module` in your script to this full path.

Comment: module is a user interface to the Modules package. The Modules package provides for the dynamic modification of the user's environment via modulefiles.